# C++ Cannot write dynamic array to file

Tags: c++, arrays, file-io, casting

I am trying to write to a binary file from a dynamic array of floats.

Here is my code:

```
FILE* file;
std::ofstream outStream;

file = fopen("mesh1.model", "w");
outStream = std::ofstream(file);

unsigned numTriangles;
float *vertices;
float *uvs;

unsigned degree = 0;

numTriangles = 2 * std::pow(4, degree); // numTriangles == 2 in this case

vertices = new float[9 * numTriangles];
uvs = new float[6 * numTriangles];

vertices[0] = -1.0f;
vertices[1] = 0.0f;
vertices[2] = 1.0f;

uvs[0] = 0.0f;
uvs[1] = 0.0f;

[....]

vertices[15] = 1.0f;
vertices[16] = 0.0f;
vertices[17] = -1.0f;

uvs[10] = 1.0f;
uvs[11] = 1.0f;

outStream.write((const char*)numTriangles, sizeof(numTriangles));
// Get runtime error on the line after this comment [access violation] (VS2013)
outStream.write((const char*)&(vertices), sizeof(float) * 9 * numTriangles); 
outStream.write((const char*)&(uvs), sizeof(float) * 6 * numTriangles);

delete[] vertices;
delete[] uvs;

fclose(file);
file = fopen("mesh1.model", "r");
```

I looked at past comments with similar issues, but they have not helped.

One of them used `reinterpret_cast` which I tried and did not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your culprit:

```
outStream.write((const char*)numTriangles, sizeof(numTriangles));
```

The first parameter should be the address of the data to write, not the data itself!
Casting your data to the expected pointer will shut up the compiler, but produce either garbage or a core dump (illegal read access).

You might want to use something like that instead:

```
outStream.write((const char *) & numTriangles, sizeof(numTriangles));
```

`reinterpret_cast` is not really necessary, unless you think C++ is not verbose enough as it is.

`ofstream` works well with the stream interface, that is when you want to put textual representations of objects into a file, taking advantage of the `<<` operator overloads.

To write pure binary, `ofstream` is just plain crappy, since it does not offer a transparent `const void *` pointer and forces you to cast every single data block you try to write.

My advice would be to stick to STDIO and use `fwrite`, since you started with an `fopen` anyway. Much less verbose and does the job just as well.

EDIT:

All this being said, as cdhowie pointed out, writing raw blocks of binary data may cause all sorts of problems.

Suppose for instance you recompile your code on a different platform where `unsigned` has a different size (which is as simple as building for x64 instead of x32). What will become of your data when the newly compiled executable tries to read it?

If you intend on writing lasting code, you might consider putting more effort into a portable serialization code, that would at least use values independent of native binary representation (at the very least, fixed size integers and floating point numbers and endianness handling).

Another solution might be to write textual data and let a dedicated library like `gzip` compress it. That might also let you take advantage of the `iostream` philosophy, that is to write objects in form of textual data.

Comment: `reinterpret_cast` is not necessary, but neither is `std::unique_ptr`. We're smart enough to manage our own memory, right? ... Maybe, but we use these facilities because they are *safer than the alternative* even if they are more verbose. Using C-style casts [can lead to all sorts of problems](https://anteru.net/2007/12/18/200/) when it decides to cast in a way you weren't expecting. The C++ style casts allow you to exactly specify what kind of cast you want instead of playing russian roulette with your casts. This is better because it's safer and there are fewer surprises.

Comment: @cdhowie `ofstream` byte block write interface is the one playing Russian roulette here. What does matter is not whether you neatly reinterpret_cast the data you write or simply C-style cast it. What matters is that you need to make sure the data and size are consistent, which is a conceptual weakness in the interface. You could have expected an interface that at least computes the size of the object written, plus an extra optional parameter to write multiple copies, but instead `ofstream` does no better than `fwrite`, adding the unnecessary chore of a useless cast.

Answer (score 0):

All three of your `write()` calls are wrong.  But before we get into that, there is one thing we need to get out of the way:

**Never use a C-style cast in C++.**

C++ has its own, more specific cast operators and you should always use them.  In this case, you want to use `reinterpret_cast`.

The first case is wrong because you are casting a non-pointer to a pointer. You should instead be taking a pointer to `numTriangles`.

```
outStream.write((const char*)numTriangles, sizeof(numTriangles));

// Should be this:

outStream.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&numTriangles), sizeof(numTriangles));
```

In the other two cases, `vertices` and `uvs` are already pointers and point to the data you want to save, so here you *should not* be using the `&` operator:

```
outStream.write((const char*)&(vertices), sizeof(float) * 9 * numTriangles); 
outStream.write((const char*)&(uvs), sizeof(float) * 6 * numTriangles);

// Should be this:

outStream.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(vertices), sizeof(float) * 9 * numTriangles); 
outStream.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(uvs), sizeof(float) * 6 * numTriangles);
```

Comment: Here the real problem is the crappy `ofstream` interface that forces to use pointers to chars. A function that would write a dozen different items would be bloated with functionally unnecessary casts, hiding the relevant part of the code (the names and sizes of the actually written data) in a clutter of verbose `reinterpret_cast`s. Besides, the real danger here is to have a mismatch between addresses and sizes, which is equally present with `ofstream` and `fwrite`. Better drop the inadequate `ofstream` and use another interface like `fwrite` that allows direct address use, IMHO.

Comment: @kuroineko Well, a better solution would be proper data serialization, not writing out raw blocks of memory. Try to load this data on an architecture with a different endianness or with different padding requirements and the whole thing will blow up. `fwrite()` is functionally equivalent to what OP is doing; the syntax might be a tad nicer but that's it.

Comment: I could not agree more, but proposing a change of architecture would go beyond the scope of the original question :).